# How to make a "Regular Expression Template" that gets values in between certain places. Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, templates

I am inquiring about how to make something similar to a [Python Template](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKvb1IPrrR8) in reverse, using regular expressions. A template for a quadratic would look something like this:
("${**a**}x^2+${**b**}x+${**c**}")
How can one reverse this to make it instead take a string and pull out a, b, c.

The reason behind this question is I was recently trying to perform the  task to get **a** and **b** like this:

```
    a = []
    for character in self.text:
        if re.search("\d", character):
          a.append(character)
        else:
            break
    b = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % ("\d*[\w][\^]2[+-]", "\w[+-]"), self.text).group(1)


    return a, b
```

It works fine but it's not very pythonic and it's very cumbersome. I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible start on what I think you're asking for -- it uses regular expressions to tease out the quadratic constants:

```
import re

EXAMPLES = [
    "6x^2",
    "5x",
    "4",
    "x^2 - 3x - 4",
    "6x^2 + 11x - 35",
    "x^2 - 7x",
    "2x^2 + 5x + 3",
    "5x - 3",
    "x^2 - 3",
]

QUADRATIC_PATTERN = r"(?:(\d*)[a-z]\^2)?" r"(?:\s*[-+]\s*)?" r"(?:(\d*)[a-z])?" r"(?:\s*[-+]\s*)?" r"(\d*)?"

for equation in EXAMPLES:
    matchobj = re.search(QUADRATIC_PATTERN, equation)

    if (matchobj):
        print(equation, ": a =", matchobj.group(1), "b =", matchobj.group(2), "c =", matchobj.group(3))
    else:
        print("misread equation:", equation)
```

The `QUADRATIC_PATTERN` is defined as a series of raw strings that Python will concatenate into one string -- this just made it easier to develop and debug.  See `re.VERBOSE` for a different/better way to do this.

The above produces:

```
6x^2 : a = 6 b = None c = 
5x : a = None b = 5 c = 
4 : a = None b = None c = 4
x^2 - 3x - 4 : a =  b = 3 c = 4
6x^2 + 11x - 35 : a = 6 b = 11 c = 35
x^2 - 7x : a =  b = 7 c = 
2x^2 + 5x + 3 : a = 2 b = 5 c = 3
5x - 3 : a = None b = 5 c = 3
x^2 - 3 : a =  b = None c = 3
```

Where `None` means the term wasn't present and an empty result means the term was present but no constant was given.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you!